# Count how many days left from date and month field

Tags: mysql

what is the query to calculate how many days_left?
i have date field, and month field,
already try using datediff, but it didnt know how to make datediff recognize warranty_months as month value.

this is my table

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | purchase_date | warranty_months |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 25/01/2020    |        12       |
| 2  | 26/01/2020    |        10       |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

expected result

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
| id | purchase_date | warranty_months | days_left |
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 1  | 25/01/2020    |        12       |   365     |
| 2  | 26/01/2020    |        24       |   730     |
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DATEDIFF` here after adjusting the purchase date forward by the length of the warranty:

```
SELECT
    id,
    purchase_date,
    warranty_months,
    DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, warranty_months, purchase_date), purchase_date) AS days_left
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo